# shared library not found during compilation

Tags: linux, shared-libraries

So I got several shared libraries that I am trying to permanently install on my Ubuntu system but I am having some difficulty with it.

I want to install the libraries and the headers in a separate folder under `/usr/local/lib` and `/usr/local/include` (for example a folder named `agony`) so it would be clean and removing them would just require that I delete those folders. so it looks something like this:

```
/usr/local/lib/agony/libbtiGPIO.so
/usr/local/lib/agony/libbtiDSP.so
...

/usr/local/include/agony/GPIO.h
/usr/local/include/agony/DSP.h
...
```

And I added a file here `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/agony.conf` which include a line describing the path to the library folder:

```
$ cat /etc/ld.so.conf.d/agony.conf
/usr/local/lib/agony
```

and I perform `sudo ldconfig` to update the library database.
So to double check if the library is found I do `ldconfig -p | grep bti*` and
I see the following result:

```
$ ldconfig -p | grep bti
    ...

    libbtiGPIO.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/agony/libbtiGPIO.so
    libbtiDSP.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/agony/libbtiDSP.so
    ...
```

At this point I should be able to use the libraries without specifying the library path. But When I attempt to compile an application without providing the library path (-L) it fails. However, when I supply `gcc` with the library path ex:

```
gcc source.c -L /usr/local/lib/agony output -lbtiGPIO -lbtiDSP
```

it works!!

I don't want to use `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable because this library is going to be used everywhere on the system and I don't want other compilers to worry about providing `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> At this point I should be able to use the libraries without specifying the library path

Here lies the confusion.

You have built your shared library `libbtiGPIO.so` (just sticking with that one),
placed it in `/usr/local/lib/agony`, and updated the `ldconfig` database accordingly.

The effect of that is when you *run* a program that *has been* linked with `libbtiGPIO`
then the dynamic linker (`/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.21.so`, or similar) will know where to look 
to load that library into the process and you will not need to tell it by setting an `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in the environment.

However, you haven't done anything that affects the list of default library
search directories that are hardwired into your build of `gcc`, that it passes to
the linker (`/usr/bin/ld`) when you *link* a program with `libbtiGPIO` in the first place.

That list of default search directories is what you will find if your do a verbose
build of your program - `gcc -v ...` - and then pick out the value of `LIBRARY_PATH`
from the output, e.g.

```
LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/:\
        /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/:\
        /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../../lib/:\
        /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:\
        /lib/../lib/:\
        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:\
        /usr/lib/../lib/:\
        /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../:\
        /lib/:\
        /usr/lib
```

`/usr/local/lib/agony` is not one of those and to make it one of those you
would have to build `gcc` from source yourself. Hence, in order to link your
program with `libbtiGPIO` you still need to tell `ld` where to find it with
`-L/usr/local/lib/agony -lbtiGPIO`.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up Mike. So when I install a 3rd party library using apt-get for example, it must install the shared libraries and somewhere like `/usr/lib` because I don't specify the library path when I use those libraries. What if the 3rd party libraries name is the same as another one on the system? This seems like a really bad design from first impression.

Comment: @Bloody-Band-Aid A package can't get into the distro's package feeds with the same name as a prior one. The distro controls its package namespace. If I install a source package, outside the package manager's control, by default it will install under `/usr/local`,
outside the distro's space. Any problem I encounter with unmanaged installations is entirely my own headache. Installing two libraries with the same name to the same installation prefix just can't be done. I could install them them to different installation prefixes,
`/usr/local/fooA`, `/usr/local/fooB`, but that would be mad.

Answer (score 0):

man, you misunderstand the procedure of complier and link.

First, **libbtiGPIO.so** is a shared link library not a static link library. it is important to know those difference .

Then you need to know something else. changing **ld.so.conf.d/*.conf** and run **sudo ldconfig**, it affects the procedure of link. in other words, if you don't add agony.conf and **sudo ldconfig**, you will receive a error when you run **./a.out** rather than **gcc source.c -L ....**, the gcc command can run successfully even thougth you don't ldconfig.

Finally,if you don't pollute the LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable, you have to add -L ... options in your gcc command. What'more, if you don't want to input too many words in your shell frequently, you can learn to use Makefile.

Comment: I never said it was static, read the first line where I wrote "shared" but the gist of what you said syncs with what Mike just said. Thank you